# Compilation problems on my C++ project developed with Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, compilation, cocos2d-x

I use Xcode 4 to develop my C++ project. Everything worked well during several weeks but since few days, I have got compilation problems:

- when I perform a modification to my code, I have to recompile the project to know if my code is correct or wrong...(to get the warnings in orange or the errors in red)
- even if I recompile, the wrong code (which should be highlighted in orange/red) is not always detected/highlighted...
- the errors are properly detected/highlighted on some parts of the code but not on some others.

PS: to be accurate, my project is a Cocos2d-x project (but I think that is not the issue ; what is important is that it is a C++ project)

Comment: Are we talking about compilation errors, or run-time errors?

Comment: I speak about compilation errors (which are not highlighted in red or orange like errors or warnings should be). I have edited my question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Organizer, find your project and delete its DerivedData folder. Xcode will then index your project, and you should be good again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have the same issue. Any other ideas ? By the way, two folders are created in Derived Data for my project, is it normal ?